# How to import custom framework into project with cocapods

Tags: swift, xcode, ld

I currently have an Framework which uses Alamofire, JWT and CryptoSwift which are installed using cocapods.

My framework sucsessfully builds when I use the 'Generic iOS device'. When I go to drag it into my Application and tell it to create a copy, it appears in the 'linked frameworks and libraries' section on the general page. The problem is, when I build my application, I get an error saying that the image is not found. To fix the issue, I removed it from the 'linked frameworks and libraries' section and added it to the 'embedded binaries part'. This however, did not fix my problem.

How can I import a custom framework made out of 3rd party frameworks installed with cocopods? When I write code using my framework, it gives me auto completion so this means that Xcode recognises that my framework is there, however it does not run it on my physical iPhone 6s

Comment: If your project requires cocoa pods, you should be writing a pod file which dictates which pods to add to which target. Then performing a pod installation with `pod install` in your project directory will take care of downloading the pods and generating a `.xcworkspace` file for you.

Comment: @MichaelFourre It it possible to make my own .framework rather then using it with all the pods? I'm making the framework so my project/workspace code is not as big.

Comment: Probably. I don't have experience doing that so I can't speak for how it's done. You could also just make your framework a pod, of course. It's quite easy to whip up a podspec in a few minutes.

Comment: Runtime 'Image not found' error usually means that you framework should appear in Embedded binaries. First you remove framework from "Linked frameworks and Libraries", then add it to 'Embedded Binaries' which automatically adds it to 'Linked frameworks and libraries' as well. I recommend to clean the project folder before build.